# CSS background-size thin black lines on top of images

Tags: css, image, cross-browser, background-size

I'm having a problem with image sizing between Chrome and Safari. On our Webshop ([www.85online.de](http://www.85online.de)) I get these thin black lines on top of some images in the product grid.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFDcZ.png)

I found that the problem is caused by "background-size: cover" in Chrome. When I change the value to "background-size: 100%" these lines disappear, but now they show up in Safari.

Anyone having the same problem? How can I fix this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please add the relevant code as a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can have a better look at the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a `background-image` problem, your `background-image` on **repeat by default**, So you need to add CSS

```
.cmp-product-thumb .thumb-image .container-image {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```